# Wordpress site failes to load js and css

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

I have this weird problem with my Wordpress Website. I worked on localhost and afterwards I tied to get my site online but i modified some configuration files and i don't know witch one is the fault. I am using XAMPP. The website right now is seems to not load js and css. Also on console log it gives 404 error for not fiinding the files it needs.
Landing page:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0ien.png)

Another Page:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaAOX.png)

Answer (score 0):

do you use gzip compression or such as it? if yes try to disable it, and make sure you have the right path

Comment: No,i dont use g-zip

Comment: I am mostly interested in files how define the path of the index.php or can overwrite them causing the problem

Comment: you mean the .htaccess ?

Comment: Yes, i think that's what causing issue but I don't have the old file

Answer (score 0):

First, check that the file permissions are correct.

Also, if you have changed anything on your .htaccess files, overwrite them with the default ones: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress

Also it's always a good idea to go to the permalinks page (/wp-admin/options-permalink.php) to update the links of all dependencies to the new URL.